# Can I check if a user is already in the database before sending it? (Mongoose and Next JS)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am having a problem with my code where I am sending users to the database even though he is already in there. How can I check if the user is already (based on both, name and age) in the database before I send it to it to prevent this problem?
Here are the codes:

index.js

```
            async function handleSubmitCreateClient () {
                try {
                    const { data } = await api.post("/user", { name, age })
                    setUsers(users.concat(data.data))
                    setName ("")
                    setAge ("")
                    Toast ({
                        title: "Success!",
                        status: 'success',
                        duration: 9000,
                        isClosable: true,
                    })
                    setIsLoading(false);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log("Fail");
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }
            }
```

api

```
    case "POST":
      try {
        const { name, age } = req.body;
    
        if (!name && !age) throw "invalid data";
        const client = await Client.create({ name, age });
    
        res.status(201).json({success:true, data:client});
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error });
      }
      break;
```

Thank you in advance!
I have tried to make some changes to the code but no success, it still doesn't check the user. So, I would like to know the best way to perform this verification.

I already tried some different ways to insert the verification but none of them works...

The one I got closer to the answer was this one, where I insert an if condition on the **index.js** page, but as soon as I **refresh** the page it **forgets** that the **User already sent the name and age**, and end it up adding the user again to the database:

```
if (users.some((user) => user.owner_of === owner_of && user.token_id === token_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if a user exists first. If so, don't continue with the POST.

```
case "POST":
      try {
        const { name, age } = req.body;
    
        if (!name && !age) throw "invalid data";

        const clientExists = await Client.find({ name });
        if (clientExists) {
          throw "User already exists";
        }

        const client = await Client.create({ name, age });
    
        res.status(201).json({success:true, data:client});
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error });
      }
      break;
```

Comment: It didn't work, I end up getting a new error "Request failed with status code 500"...

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen now. If the user exists, you will fail with a 500 error. What is it you are expecting to happen?

Comment: I meant that even though the user is not in the database I get this same message

Comment: My guess is that you should be using User.find and User.create. Have you set up the User model correctly with Mongoose? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: The fact that you have Client.create is a bit of a red flag, but I was assuming that you had simply named your model Client.